# google map pans off the 'edge' of the earth

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Has anyone else found it problematic that Google Maps (now) allow you to pan beyond the poles. It used to stop at the poles, right?

A site I'm working on performs a location-based query on our server every time the user pans or zooms a map. This is causing errors because the queries that are triggered by the user panning off the edge of the map are nonsensical.

For now I'm handling the edge case, so to speak, on the server side, but it is not a very good user experience on the client side. Does anyone have a solution for preventing over-panning?

Thanks

screenshot: 
[image: edge of the earth!]

Comment: You can do this on the Google Maps site too, so it's quite normal

Comment: You could always tell the user that the world's flat and that "here be dragons".

Comment: Yes, dragons. That or The Nothing. Good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to avoid the gray area is to limit the user's panning, following this example, "Range Limiting"; however, it's written for Version 2.

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/range.htm

It's straightforward to have it work in Version 3, http://jsfiddle.net/44e6y/9/ but there are drawbacks:

- it relies on the center of the map being inside a box, so
- zooming in will further limit the viewable area (doesn't matter if you're not interested in the poles, but you could have an array of LatLngBounds for various zooms, it becomes a necessity for seeing Greenland)
- as a result of the last point, I force the minimum zoom to be 2 for the JSFiddle iframe size. If the map will take up the whole screen, the minimum zoom may be higher to avoid displaying the gray area. In general, the higher the min. zoom, the more predictable the behavior.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that out. Seems like it should be built in to google maps though, no?

Comment: I think the default behavior is to cover cases like setting the center  near a pole when the zoom is low. Technically you have to display something if the point is centered in its div. Still, I agree that it would be nice to have an option to automatically limit panning.

Comment: Finally getting back to this. Your solution works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had the same problem and the accepted only targets zoom of the level 2 (other zoom levels fail in the example), I went to try to find a formula, but didn't succeed, so I hard-coded in first 8 zoom levels with values. Obviously, this could be expanded to a fully working example, but I think this is good enough for 99% of the cases.

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gasC2/)

I also added another listener to make it work better.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
      checkBounds();});
```